# WP All Export Custom XML order lines loop error

Tags: wpallimport

I need a customized xml for orders, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:root xmlns:ns1="https://web.one.com">
    <ns1:Orders>
    <!-- BEGIN LOOP --> 
        <ns1:Order ns1:ownCode="{Order ID}">
            <ns1:Customer>000000</ns1:Customer>
            <ns1:Date>[date("Y-m-d")]</ns1:Date>
            <ns1:ServiceDate>{Completed Date}</ns1:ServiceDate>
            <ns1:Addressee>
                <ns1:Name>{Shipping First Name} {Shipping Last Name}</ns1:Name>
                <ns1:Phone>{Shipping Phone}</ns1:Phone>
                <ns1:ShippingAddr>
                    <ns1:Address>{Shipping Address 1} {Shipping Address 2}</ns1:Address>
                    <ns1:ZipCode>{Shipping Postcode}</ns1:ZipCode>
                    <ns1:Location>{Shipping City}</ns1:Location>
                    <ns1:Province>{Shipping State}</ns1:Province>
                    <ns1:Country>{Shipping Country}</ns1:Country>
                </ns1:ShippingAddr>
            </ns1:Addressee>
            <ns1:Anonymous>"true"</ns1:Anonymous>
            <ns1:RemarksLabel>"CompanyLabel"</ns1:RemarksLabel>
            <ns1:Lines>
                <ns1:Line ownid="{Order Line ID}">
                    <ns1:Product id="{SKU}">
                        <ns1:ProductName>{Product Name}</ns1:ProductName>
                        <ns1:Rate>{Item Cost}</ns1:Rate>
                        <ns1:SupplierRef>{Product ID}</ns1:SupplierRef>
                    </ns1:Product>
                    <ns1:Quantity>{Quantity}</ns1:Quantity>
                    <ns1:Amount>{Item Total}</ns1:Amount>
                </ns1:Line>
            </ns1:Lines>
        </ns1:Order>
    <!-- END LOOP -->
    </ns1:Orders>
</ns1:root>
```

It works for orders, displays all orders from all customers
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1NO6.png)

but gives an error when I add the details of the order lines.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RvLt.png)

Is something wrong?
Every help is welcome!

the lines should be like this:

```
<ns1:Lines>
    <ns1:Line ns1:ownid="19998">
        <ns1:Product ns1:id="1">
            <ns1:ProductName>Product A</ns1:ProductName>
            <ns1:Rate>10</ns1:Rate>
            <ns1:SupplierRef>10000</ns1:SupplierRef>
        </ns1:Product>
        <ns1:Quantity>1</ns1:Quantity>
        <ns1:Amount>10</ns1:Amount>
    </ns1:Line>
    <ns1:Line ns1:ownid="20000">
        <ns1:Product ns1:id="2">
            <ns1:ProductName>Product A</ns1:ProductName>
            <ns1:Rate>20</ns1:Rate>
            <ns1:SupplierRef>30000</ns1:SupplierRef>
        </ns1:Product>
        <ns1:Quantity>2</ns1:Quantity>
        <ns1:Amount>40</ns1:Amount>
    </ns1:Line>
</ns1:Lines>
```